centos7 yum failed because "Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: centos-nfs-ganesha28"
I am building some dependencies on CentOS 7.9.
The error occurs:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: centos-nfs-ganesha28

Then I get the local repo information and find the baseurl of repo centos-nfs-ganesha28 is missing:
========================================================================================= repo: centos-nfs-ganesha28 =========================================================================================
[centos-nfs-ganesha28]
async = True
bandwidth = 0
base_persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7
baseurl =
cache = 0
cachedir = /var/tmp/yum-yy-2LsqLm/x86_64/7/centos-nfs-ganesha28
check_config_file_age = True
compare_providers_priority = 80
cost = 1000
deltarpm_metadata_percentage = 100
deltarpm_percentage =
enabled = 1
enablegroups = True
exclude =
failovermethod = priority
ftp_disable_epsv = False
gpgcadir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/centos-nfs-ganesha28/gpgcadir-ro
gpgcakey =
gpgcheck = True
gpgdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/centos-nfs-ganesha28/gpgdir-ro
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-Storage
hdrdir = /var/tmp/yum-yy-2LsqLm/x86_64/7/centos-nfs-ganesha28/headers
http_caching = all
includepkgs =
ip_resolve =
keepalive = True
keepcache = True
mddownloadpolicy = sqlite
mdpolicy = group:small
mediaid =
metadata_expire = 21600
metadata_expire_filter = read-only:present
metalink =
minrate = 0
mirrorlist =
mirrorlist_expire = 86400
name = CentOS-7 - NFS Ganesha 2.8
old_base_cache_dir = /var/cache/yum
password =
persistdir = /var/lib/yum/repos/x86_64/7/centos-nfs-ganesha28
pkgdir = /var/tmp/yum-yy-2LsqLm/x86_64/7/centos-nfs-ganesha28/packages
proxy = False
proxy_dict =
proxy_password =
proxy_username =
repo_gpgcheck = False
retries = 10
skip_if_unavailable = False
ssl_check_cert_permissions = True
sslcacert =
sslclientcert =
sslclientkey =
sslverify = True
throttle = 0
timeout = 30.0
ui_id = centos-nfs-ganesha28
ui_repoid_vars = releasever,
   basearch
username =


I ran the same commands in the context of Ubuntu 20.04 and it succeeded.
So what's the url of this repository? I am confused about the issue.
